# Нужно чтобы программа на Python по нажатию Ctrl+K выводила дату в место нахождения курсора

Tags: python

Это код с выводом даты в нужном формате.
Нужно чтобы программа на Python по нажатию Ctrl+K выводила эту дату в место нахождения курсора.

```
# Импортируем модуль для работы с датой.
from datetime import datetime
# Сохраняем в переменную now текущую дату.
now = datetime.now()
# Выводим текущую дату в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД ЧЧ-ММ.
print("{:%Y-%m-%d %H-%M}".format(now))
```

Answer (score 0):

Узнал.

Для этого можно использовать модуль keyboard. Он позволяет привязать функцию к клавише, а затем вызывать эту функцию при нажатии на соответствующую клавишу.

Ниже приведен пример кода, который выводит текущую дату в место нахождения курсора при нажатии Ctrl+K:

```
import keyboard
import datetime

def insert_date():
date = 




datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
keyboard.write(date)

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+k', 
insert_date)

keyboard.wait()
```